# How I get few words of a Post - WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I get the first few words of a post that does not have excerpt?

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => 'Energy',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'author_name'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );

 foreach($posts_array as $postCategory)
{
  echo get_the_title( $postCategory->ID );
  echo get_permalink( $postCategory->ID );
  echo get_the_excerpt( $postCategory->ID ); // THIS WITH OU WITHOUT EXCERPT DOES NOT WORK
}
```

The code is printing the title and the permalink but it does not print the first few words of the post.

I would like to understand how to print the first few words of the post, whether or not it has the excerpt delimiter.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                  $trimtitle = get_the_content($post->ID);
                  $shorttitle = wp_trim_words( $trimtitle, $num_words = 15, $more = '… ' );?> 
                  <?php echo $shorttitle; ?>
```

Comment: Please change 15 on basis of u want to display character

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to add the following function:

```
function truncate_string ($string, $maxlength) {

    // Set the replacement for the "string break" in the wordwrap function
    $cutmarker = "**cut_here**";

    // Checking if the given string is longer than $maxlength
    if (strlen($string) > $maxlength) {

        // Using wordwrap() to set the cutmarker
        // NOTE: wordwrap (PHP 4 >= 4.0.2, PHP 5)
        $string = wordwrap($string, $maxlength, $cutmarker);

        // Exploding the string at the cutmarker, set by wordwrap()
        $string = explode($cutmarker, $string);

    }

    // returning $string
    return $string;

}
```

Then add the following inside your foreach loop:

```
$content_post = get_post( $postCategory->ID );
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo truncate_string( $content, 75 );
```

(change 75 to whatever length you'd like)